# EAR in Eclipse Juno with JBOSS 7 does not publish automatically

Tags: jboss7.x, ear, eclipse-juno

Hi guys previously i was deploying my project WAR on JBOSS AS 7 and whenever resources got changed the eclipse Juno auto republished the war file. But since I added my war into a ear and deployed that ear on JBOSS, now eclipse doesn't auto republish. I also tried changing publishing setting but nothing worked for me. Now I republish manually after every single change. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but got it to work after checking the 'Deploy projects as compressed archives' box (open up the server configuration and go to the Deployments tab)